# When was it known that natural numbers and rational numbers correspond one-to-one?

Tags: mathematics

I would not be surprised if ancient mathematicians had found it.

Comment: I would be surprised if it was ever stated before 1850.

Comment: Cantor proved it in 1873 by zigzagging the square table of all fractions, see [Veisdal, Cantor and Dedekind's Early Correspondence](https://www.privatdozent.co/p/cantor-and-dedekinds-early-correspondence). Before that nobody thought of even asking the question, especially not ancient mathematicians who abhorred actual infinities. And not even Bolzano or Dedekind.

Comment: Your statement "I would not be surprised..." only shows how radical was the revolution that Cantor made.

Comment: Ancient mathematicians didn't even realize that it was an interesting question! For them -- and for nearly everyone else unti Cantor -- infinity meant uncountable.

Comment: I have some extensive notes I've made on this topic that include statements (appearing in personal letters and publications) made by (or ascribed to) Cantor, Schoenflies, Weierstrass, Dedekind, Jourdain. However, they are in a .pdf document that will require some effort to accurately reproduce as an answer here (copy/paste works, but much fixing of formatting errors is needed and all math symbols need to be written from scratch), and I'm extremely busy with day-job stuff right now, so it will take several days, maybe more than a week, to finish it (working a little each day, when I'm able to).

Comment: In looking at the web page @Conifold cited, maybe I can skip a lot of what I was thinking of posting and just summarize who did/said what and when, and only include the stuff I have that pertains to Weierstrass. Nonetheless, this is still not something I have time to take care of right now . . .

Comment: @Conifold maybe you should just publish that as an answer

Comment: Galileo considered the 1-1 correspondence between positive integers and perfect squares as well as the density of perfect squares up to $N$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. I'm sure he would have thought about whether there was a correspondence with fractions, if it occurred to him. As far as I know, he didn't write about it.